# Is there any way to Disable -Wmultichar warning from C++ source code?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, compiler-warnings

I can use the compiler flag `-Wno-multichar` to disable the multi-character warning .But, I want to do this from source code.

So, I tried `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmultichar"` ,but it does not work.

I saw some posts from 7 years ago about this bug .Now, is there any other way to disable the warning this from my .cpp file or is it impossible???

**Note**:- This works in C .

Comment: Why would you want to disable it at all? Most likely the code has some unintentional use of multicharacter char literals. I've rarely seen appropriate use for this.

Comment: I'm a bit curious what use case you have for a multi-charackter-literal. Usually it means you have a typo, like confusing single and double quotes or accidentally typing two or more characters in a character literal.

Comment: Looks like you can't: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c401072f991d07e2 Coliru has a pretty actual GCC version usually.

Comment: *Note that not all diagnostics are modifiable; at the moment only warnings (normally controlled by `-W...') can be controlled, and not all of them. Use -fdiagnostics-show-option to determine which diagnostics are controllable and which option controls them*

Comment: What @hans said,, and also note that support for valid multicharacter literals is compiler specific by defintion. I am pretty sure that GCC won't warn about the valid ones supported by it.

Comment: @churill I was playing with different errors and warnings ,then I saw that we can't disable the warning from source code. The bug still lives and it's impossible to disable from source code.  